# How to typedef 3 bits variable that's inside of a struct?

Tags: c, struct, typedef

I want to typedef a 3 bit variable I made inside a struct and I want to use it normally like `int x=5;` not `structName.x=5;`, Example of what I mean:

```
typedef struct{
    unsigned x:3;
} v3bits;

typedef v3bits.x uint3_t;

int main(){
    uint3_t x=5; 
    return 0;
}
```

How could I do that?

Answer (score 3):

You can't.  There is no way to create a 3-bit integer type in C.  You can instead use a wider integer type like uint8_t.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible in C at least. use wider type datatype

Answer (score 0):

You declare a struct with a field in it:

> typedef struct{ ... unsigned x:3; } v3bits;

...and assign it an "alias", v3bits, which refers to an (otherwise) unnamed type "struct something". And this is ok. Then you try to create a new type using a field instead of a type:

> typedef v3bits.x uint3_t;   (v3bits.x is not a type)

`Typedef` is used to create new type names from other ones - the result is only to have a short name instead of a long one made up of (maybe) several parts. For example:

```
typedef unsigned int * puint_t;
```

would let you to write, from now on, `puint_t` instead of `unsigned int *`.

So, the first problem is that you can't use typedef to give a name to a variable or a field. The second problem is that you want an integer type made up of three bits. This is not supported by C. But, you can read and write into your v3bits.x field - this would actually use only 3 bits. Perhaps using some macro you can obtain something similar to what you want.